# Multiples imagesView with text in a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm making a soundbox for me and my friends in android studio.
I've got a simple Scroll view, that I filled up with multiple constraintLayout that each contains 2 imageView with each of having a line of text under it.

The problem is that when I run the app, I only see the 2 first layouts, i've no idea what's going on and this is probably not the good way to do it.

What's the best solution here? Here is the xml code :

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="800dp"
    android:background="#353535"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonStopAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/red_perso"
                android:text="Stop tout"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idTheoGonfle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/theosouffle" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idChuteCJ"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cjchute" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTheoGonfle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:width="150dp"
                    android:background="#FFEB3B"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Théo gonfle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idTheoGonfle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:width="150dp"
                    android:background="#FFEB3B"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idChuteCJ" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like you are begginer.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="800dp"
android:background="#353535"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

look like your problem
android:layout_height="800dp"
You set the fix height. Change it to match_parent.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout. And change root layout to FrameLayout or remove it.

Comment: Thank you, working nicely to fix the layout problem.

And the layouts were showing but the pictures I used were sample, wich is why they weren't there

Comment: I am not sure somebody can help you with it. It needs a code how you download images. I think it is another question.